# Want to fix this page background

Tags: html, css

I want to fix this page  (http://l2topserver.com/l2topserver)  just to have a right banner link. I made this code 
but when the screen's resolution the page is broken in the right side. What settings can I use that the page won't break?

First snippet

```css
.header11 a {
  display: block;
  background-image: url("http://www.l2topserver.com/test/1.jpg");
  padding-left: 395px;
  padding-top: 1000px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="header11">
  <div align="left">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second snippet

```css
.header111 a {
    display: block;
    background-image: url("http://www.l2topserver.com/test/2.jpg");
  
    padding-left:395px;
    padding-top:1000px;
    width:100px;
    left: 1410px; top: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header111">
    <div align="right">
       <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
       </a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `right: 0;` in the second image.

```css
.header11 a {
    display: block;
    background-image: url("http://www.l2topserver.com/test/1.jpg");

    padding-left:395px;
    padding-top:1000px;
    width:5%;
    left: 5px; top: 10px;
    position: fixed;

}

.header111 a {
    display: block;
    background-image: url("http://www.l2topserver.com/test/2.jpg");

    padding-left:395px;
    padding-top:1000px;
    width:5%;
    right: 0; 
    top: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}
```